# How do I get the true height of the parent View containing the TextView？

Tags: android

I ran into A problem while developing Android: IN the following code, I have a parent layout -A that contains textView - B with multiple lines of TextView. I can't get the true height of A because TextView only counts as one row, so how can I get the true height of A?

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/A"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="black"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:text="this is a text!this is a text!this is a text!this is a text!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use the android:lines="5" attribute to show the multiple lines and expand the height.

Answer (score 1):

The true height of your view would not be known until it gets inflated during the run time so after the view have inflated in an activity.

To do this at run time you can attach a OnGlobalLayoutListener on the view tree as shown below.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.YOUR VIEW ID);
ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver(); 
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onGlobalLayout() { 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                this.layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } 
        int width  = layout.getMeasuredWidth();
        int height = layout.getMeasuredHeight(); 

    } 
});
```